# General ? - The maximum number of segmented/ split bytes sent over a connection using TCP Protocol?

Tags: java, php, .net, sockets, tcp

just wanted to ask what should be the limit of bytes when data is being sent back and forth from server and client, with the great feed back i have go i understand this a bit more, so now the question is what are the size of segmented bytes sent over a connection?

So if i set a buffer size of 3072 bytes to be sent to the server from the client and the same when sending data from server to client, how are these bytes segmented? and what would be the maximum number of bytes that is sent over a connection so that the bytes dont get segmented?

Comment: is nagle enabled or disabled?

Comment: Is *which* number of bytes dependent on those things? Are you caring about the individual packets? Do you really need to?

Comment: @MarcGravell, how do i enable or disable nagle in java?

Comment: @JonSkeet, with the help of stack overflow and articles online i have developed a live audio broadcast. Because the audio format produces bytes of 174600 this is to large to be sent across the server and back. So what i did was split the data and sent the bytes like so and i set these split bytes to 3072. The reason why i ask this question is that the more bytes i set when i send the data into segments the better quality that the audio produces. . Thanks for replying appreciated.

Comment: @redoc01: 174600 bytes *isn't* too large to be sent over a TCP connection. But it *will* be split into packets. That's the problem - it's not clear where you're talking about packets and where you're talking about TCP as a stream protocol.

Comment: Why are you using TCP for online broadcasting? UDP is a much better fit.

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry, yes the data is sent over TCP connection.

Comment: @jgauffin, i read online that TCP was better because you don't loose any packets, is this true?

Comment: @redoc01 for broadcasting, you usually want to simply accept that packets get dropped, and handle that at the client

Comment: Read my updated answer about TCP vs UDP when streaming audio

Comment: @JonSkeet if you read the tags, its suggests TCP

Comment: @redoc01: Yes, but reading the question and comments, that doesn't make sense - because a TCP stream can *easily* support more than 174K. That's the point - you seem to be confused between TCP as a streaming protocol, and the packets that make up the stream.

Comment: @JonSkeet,HI jon i have re-written the question, sorry about before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP do not guarantee that the number of bytes sent with one send command in the client will be the same number of bytes received in the server with one receive command. TCP is stream based with means that it treats the connection as a stream of bytes and not a stream of messages.

Sending this (two sends):

1. "Hello"
2. "World"

Can be received as:

1. "HelloWorld"

or.

1. "He"
2. "llo"
3. "World"

or any other combination.

Hence you need to be able to detect when one message end and the next begins. The two most common ways is to either use a message header containing the length or a suffix (like a line feed) to detect the end of a message.

**Update**

TCP should not be used for audio streaming imho. The reason is that TCP guarantees to deliver all sent packets. Hence if TCP detects that a packet didnt arrive it will block all queued packets until the failed one arrives.

When streaming audio it's not important that all packets arrive, one lost packet wont affect the sound too much. It's better to get a little audio loss than to let the audio stream stop completely because the network protocols tries to deliver all packets.

Comment: with the help of stack overflow and articles online i have developed a live audio broadcast. Because the audio format produces bytes of 174600 this is to large to be sent across the server and back. So what i did was split the data and sent the bytes like so and i set these split bytes to 3072. The reason why i ask this question is that the more bytes i set when i send the data into segments the better quality that the audio produces. And yes i do send a message when the segments of bytes are finished. Thanks for replying appreciated.

Comment: cool, i will try UDP, i was going to try this method but when i was browsing through examples, one of the article suggested TCP but i am sure you are correct.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing protocol/library instead of inventing your own?

Comment: this is the thing, i wanted to use something free and found red5 media server to be the solution, but i couldn't even get the tutorials to work. I set up the environment in java and tried to get the test application to work but i tried for 2 days and i got fed up and decided to do it my own. I would prefer to use existing library because i don't have time. but the amount of time i spent on trying to get existing libraries to work took to long. Plus its a great learning experience to do it your self like how Spencer Ruport explained. If i didn't den wouldn't gained the knowledge great site.

Comment: i tested UDP for sending sound over a connection and to many packets are being lost and no sound can be heard, do you think i should stick with TCP?

Answer (score 1):

There will be a handshake about the `MTU` size between the one end and the other hand of the connection and according to this size and the protocols wich are used alongside with `TCP`. There is a amount of data which will be send with one packet.

However the splitting/merging of your data into packets is done by your protocol stack if you do not use a low level API.

Answer (score 1):

If you write 3000 bytes to a TCP socket you will receive 3000 bytes at the receiving peer. There is no maximum number of bytes imposed by TCP on the protocol above it. From TCP down to IP down the stack to the protocols below, yes there are limits but your application doesn't have to worry about that. The segmentation and reassambly of ethernet frames into ip datagrams etc... will be take care of behind your back.

However you do have to worry about your protocol at the application level, the one riding on top of TCP. Although TCP will deliver all the 3000 bytes there is no gaurantee that a single call of recv (or whatever the java/php language equivalent is) will return all 3000 bytes at once. You might have to call it several times before all 3000 bytes are read from the socket.

See here for more info:

[How to know when you finish receiving a TCP stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522965/how-to-know-when-you-finish-receiving-a-tcp-stream/7522986#7522986)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're writing a TCP protocol wrapper the fact that you're asking this question is a pretty good indication that you're approaching whatever problem you're trying to solve incorrectly. TCP implementations in the languages you specified act as abstractions that should make the answer to this question entirely irrelevant.

See here for my answer to a similar question about packet reassembly:
[What's the best way to monitor a socket for new data and then process that data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453609/whats-the-best-way-to-monitor-a-socket-for-new-data-and-then-process-that-data/453951#453951)